# Webview Cache error

Tags: java, android

So I'm making a quick app for my android phone with android studio to show my time table for school. Luckely for me, someone on school already made a site that displays it intstantly without having to login myself. So I only have to set a webview and load the url to the site. Easy right? But when I load the app, it instantly gives me an error.
I have searched this site and some others but I haven't found a solution that fits my problem.

Heres the code :

```
package jcorperations.zoomvlietrooster;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://vliet.tk/?id=IB1a");
    }
}
```

and Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jcorperations.zoomvlietrooster" >

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the error I am getting on my android device:

```
Webpage not available

The webpage on http://vliet.tk/?id-IB1a can't be loaded:
net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

Of course I tried other sites but I still got the same results. And looking on here haven't got me a solution yet. Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Awnser.

I put the permision for internet on the wrong place. It must be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="jcorperations.zoomvlietrooster" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }
```

It will fix ERR_CACHE_MISS in the WebView. Maybe you will need to change it to **SDK_INT == 19** after some Lollipop **WebView updates**, but it works for now.

Comment: I tried it but I still got the same results. I did notice it took a bit longer to load the app, as if it was loading the page. But that could be coincidence